# Check box as a header in yajra datatable

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables, laravel-5

is it possible set checkbox as header in yajra datatable using addColumn function.

```
 ->editColumn('message', function ($data) {
            return '<a href="' . route('messages.show', [$data->id]) . '" style="color:#333;text-decoration:underline">' . $data->message . '</a>';
        })
```

In edit column, first argument is string('message'string as header). I want check box as header using addColumn in yajra datatable.

Answer (score 1):

In Datatable

```
private function getColumns()
{
    return [
        'id' => ['name' => 'id', 'data' => 'id', 'style' => 'width:90%' , 'class'=>'msg']
           ];
}
```

Edit Column

```
 ->editColumn('id', function ($data) {
            return '<input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" value="'.$data->id.'">';
        })
```

In Blade:

```
 <script>
    var htmlstr = '<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> ';
    $('.msg').html(htmlstr)
 </script>
```

Make Orderable false in datatable

```
$this->getColumns(),
            [
                'id' => [
                    'orderable' => false,
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'printable' => false,
                    'exportable' => false,
                        'class'=>'msg',
                ]
            ]
```